# ¿Como graficar las tablas de la verdad en python?

Tags: python-3.x

Hola amigos tengo una pequeña inquietud estuve haciendo las tablas de la verdad en python pero se me surgió la idea de que si estas se pudiesen agregarle una grafica la verdad he hecho el intento pero la verdad no me salió como pensaba seria de gran experiencia alguien que me explicara por favor dejo el código original de como es la tabla

```
x = input("Porfavor ingrese el valor de X: ")
y = input("porfavor ingrese el valor de y: ")

multiplica = (float(x)* 0.7) + (float(y) * 0.7)

if(multiplica > 0.5):
  tabla = 1
else:
  tabla = 0

print("el numero de la verdad es: ", tabla)
```

es decir hacer algo asi se puede hacer con python esto lo hice en paint XD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo no veo tabla alguna en la pregunta. Solo una variable que aunque se llama `tabla` es en realidad un entero que vale 1 o 0. Yo por tabla entiendo algo que tenga filas y columnas. Por otro lado quieres "graficar" la tabla ¿a qué te refieres con graficar? ¿Algún tipo de plot o quieres decir formatear para que quede alineada como tabla? (pero de nuevo, no veo tabla alguna en el código y no entiendo tampoco qué sería una "tabla de la verdad" en este caso)

Comment: si utilizar un tipo de plot en donde me grafique el dato metido y wow no sabia que tambien se podia hacer una tabla siendo sincero hasta ahora estoy aprendiendo python

lo que hace el programa es que te predice el numero es decir metes 0 0 y te va predecir el 0 pero si metes 1 0 te dara 1

Comment: ahí puse un ejemplo que hice la verdad fue una curiosidad que me surgió y si se puede hacer seria chido si me podían explicar

Comment: Esto se puede realizar sencillamente con `numpy`, pero lo que no entiendo es la función de la ecuación, si las variables `x` y `y` toman ciertos valores, ¿quieres que dentro de la gráfica en el eje "x" y el eje "y" sean dichos valores mencionados?

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer gráficas con Python suele usarse la biblioteca Matplotlib, pero debo decir que su curva de aprendizaje es pronunciada. Aún tras años usándola, cada vez que necesito hacer una gráfica tengo que mirar otra vez en la documentación cada pequeño detalle.

Dicho esto, una gráfica sencilla para tu caso podría obtenerse programando una función como esta:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def pintar_grafica(x, y, x0=0.7, y0=0.7):
  plt.scatter([0,0,1,1], [0,1,0,1], marker="o")
  plt.scatter([x],[y], marker="*")
  plt.xlabel("$x_1$")
  plt.ylabel("$x_2$")
  plt.plot([0, y0], [x0, 0])
```

La función recibe las coordenadas de un punto (x,y) que quieras mostrar, y también los puntos de corte en los ejes de la recta inclinada que quieres pintar (x0 e y0, con valores por defecto de 0.7).

Lo que hace la función es usar métodos de Matplotib para pintar puntos y líneas. Para los puntos uso `.scatter()` y para las líneas `.plot()`. En ambos casos hay que pasarle como primer parámetro una lista con las coordenadas x de los puntos a mostrar, y otra con las coordenadas y.

El primer `.scatter()` es para mostrar las cuatro "esquinas" (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) y (1,1). El otro `.scatter()` es para mostrar el punto que quieras y que se recibe como parámetro (se mostrará con una estrella naranja). El `.plot()` final es para la línea inclinada.

Así, si llamas a esta función con:

```
pintar_grafica(0.6, 0.6)
```

obtienes:

[image: Grafica]

### Mejoras

Si quieres que el gráfico se parezca más al que habías dibujado con Paint, hay aún bastantes cosas que hacer:

- Ajustar lo que matplotlib llama "spines"  que son lo que llamaríamos ejes. Queremos ahora que los ejes pasen por 0,0 y que solo se vea el eje vertical izquierdo (eje y) y el eje horizontal inferior (eje x) quitando los otros dos (línea de arriba y de la derecha de la "caja")
- Modificar los ticks en los ejes para que sean solo 0, 0.5 y 1 en lugar de los valores que matplotib pone automáticamente
- Modificar la relación de aspecto de la imagen para que sea cuadrada y las unidades en el eje x midan lo mismo que en el eje y
- Marcar tres de las "esquinas" con puntos negros gordos, pero la esquina en (0,0) con un punto blanco.
- Extender la recta azul, para que se vea mejor cómo corta los ejes. Eso implica calcular la pendiente de esa recta y usar su ecuación para extrapolar las coordenadas de un punto un poco más a la izquierda del corte con el eje y, y otro un poco más abajo del corte con el eje x.

Todo esto lo haría la siguiente función (obtenida tras múltiples consultas a manuales y ejemplos, como he dicho la interfaz no es intuitiva ni fácil de recordar):

```py
def pintar_grafica(x, y, x0=0.7, y0=0.7):

  # Ajustes al aspecto de los ejes
  fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  ax.spines["left"].set_position(("data", 0))
  ax.spines["bottom"].set_position(("data", 0))
  ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
  ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)  
  ax.set_xticks([0, 0.5, 1])
  ax.set_yticks([   0.5, 1])
  ax.set_aspect('equal')

  # Puntos de "las cuatro esquinas"
  ax.scatter([0,1,1], [1,0,1], marker="o", color="black")
  ax.scatter([0], [0], marker="o", facecolors='white', edgecolors='black', zorder=3)

  # Punto a representar
  ax.scatter([x], [y], marker="*", color="orange")
  ax.set_xlabel("$x_1$")
  ax.set_ylabel("$x_2$")

  # Calculo de la recta azul
  pendiente = -x0/y0
  delta = 0.1  # Pequeña cantidad a moverse tras los puntos de corte
  y_0 = y0 + pendiente*(-delta)
  y_1 = pendiente*delta
  ax.plot([-delta, y_0], [x0+delta, y_1])
```

Ahora el resultado de llamar a la función se verá así:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: wow amigo muy buena explicacion ahora con esta info podre mejorar mi proyecto no imagine que una simple curiosidad me diese mas ideas para mejorar mi proyecto muchas gracias